# iOS Firebase Email Verification

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

Currently working on an iOS / Swift app.

Using **Firebase**, You can send an email verification to verify the email account.

I need to Edit the Email Verification.

I have searched and Found that I can Go to the Console / Authentication / Email Templates and Edit Email address Verification, Password Reset and Change Email.

My Problem is that on Email Verification Address, I can edit a lot of fields, but I Can`t Edit the Message Field. And I MUST edit it since it's not in my country language, I want to personalize it and change it to Spanish.

Answer (score 3):

From what I can see, at the bottom of the page at Console/Authentication/Templates there is an edit tool that allows you to change the language of the authentication email.

As for changing the actual message itself, it is not allowed due to the fact that it could be abused for spam.
[image: Hidden Google help on message field]

[image: Location of changing the language]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please note that the user that posted this very old question is no longer a member on the site (username grayed out). Someone else might still appreciate your input on the topic. Have a nice day on SO :)

Answer (score 0):

To prevent spamming, Firebase only allowed certain fields to be edited. Message body is not editable but it is template based on dynamic fields

[image: Hidden Google help on message field]